# What are some techniques of constructing a good utility matrix?

Tags: game-theory, decision-theory, utility

A utility matrix is considered to be subjective and arbitrarily defined. Therefore, we run the risk of over-emphasizing or under-emphasizing the possible alternatives. Are there ways to design an optimal utility matrix?

EDIT: The utility matrix looks something like this:
[image]

Comment: What is the general design of the utility matrix ?

Comment: @callculus Stackexchange won't allow me to write down the utility matrix here (because of formatting issues). So, I am editing the question to include a picture of it.

Comment: That´s a good idea.

Comment: In general some axioms have to be considered. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Preference_(economics)

Comment: So, when you buy a gift, the preference between receiver liking it and not liking it is defined as follows: Receiver Likes Gift > Receiver Doesn't Like Gift. And when not buying a gift, we are indifferent: Receiver Likes Gift ~ Receiver Doesn't Like Gift. So, we have defined preference. Now what?

Comment: The question is too vague. A word for word posting of the exercise might be helpful.

Comment: Its not an exercise. I want to design a utility function for my own experiment. But, what numbers to put up is the issue. That's because, depending on what numbers I choose, the maximum expected utility of the 2 choices (buying or not buying) might vary. In other words, my decision is sensitive to the utility values. So, I want to know how do I more objectively choose these utility values? Has any research been done on this?

Comment: If you conduct an experiment by yourself, then ask yourself: Are you indifferent between a nice gift and a gift you wouldn´t like, if you do not receive the gift ? My utility wouldn´t be positive if I wouldn´t receive a gift. .Utility functions, in general, are different for different individuals.

Comment: This is utility from the giver's point of view. The utility of not buying a gift is positive because, well, (s)he is at least saving some money by not buying a gift. And yeah, if the giver is not buying a gift, then the receiver liking or not liking it is a moot point; therefore I thought this should an indifferent choice. Is that not correct?